# Should I create Mysql user `user@localhost` or `user@127.0.0.1`?

Tags: mysql

My server is centos 7.4, mysql 5.5.
In `my.cnf`,I set `skip-name-resolve = 0` and `skip-networking= 1`,which means mysql will use `user@127.0.0.1` even I run `user@localhost`.
Then, when I create a new user, which one is better, `user@localhost`  or `user@127.0.0.1`?

Also, you can find `root@localhost`,`root@127.0.0.1`,`root@::1` in a newly installed mysql.Actually there should be only one root user.Which one should be use?

Comment: And don't forget IPv6 : localhost = ::1

Comment: In MySQL, the `localhost` keyword is reserved for **connections using the MySQL socket** and you should use the `ip-address 127.0.0.1` for **TCP connections to the MySQL network port** on IPv4 127.0.0.1 or IPv6 `::1` - Those are not the same thing and you may actually need all those entries http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html - Please note: in error messages `127.0.0.1`( after a reverse DNS lookup) gets translated to `localhost` making debugging difficult.

Comment: @HBruijn,Is `skip-name-resolve ` should be `1`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not interchangeable. If you connect to MySQL via TCP, you need to use `@127.0.0.1` and if you use unix sockets, you use `@localhost`.

Comment: Normally, we just  run `$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);`is that TCP or sockets?

Comment: This depends on $dsn which may be 'sock:.....' or 'tcp:....'

Answer (score 1):

I tried to answer this question based on my understanding.
If you web server is same as the mysql server, then you'd better use `@localhost`.
And, `skip-name-resolve = 1` is necessary if you use `@localhost`.